# Using spring security annotations with keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak, pre-authentication

I'm just a beginner in Spring Security, but I would like to know is it possible to configure keycloak in a way that I can use `@PreAuthorize`, `@PostAuthorize`, `@Secured` and other annotations.
For example, I've configured the `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` and Spring Security in my simple Spring Rest webapp so that I have access to Principal object in my controller, like this:

```
@RestController
public class TMSRestController {

     @RequestMapping("/greeting")
     public Greeting greeting(Principal principal, @RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
        return new Greeting(String.format(template, name));
     }
...
}
```

But when I try this (just an example, actually I want to execute custom EL expression before authorization):

```
@RestController
public class TMSRestController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public Greeting greeting(Principal principal, @RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
        return new Greeting(String.format(template, name));
    }
...
}
```

I get exception:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

In my spring security config I enabled global method security:

What do I need to make this spring security annotations work? Is it possible to use this annotation in this context at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have to configure Spring Security using Keycloak. Take a look at the [adapter documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter) for an annotation based configuration. Once that's set up your Spring Security annotations will work on authorized calls.

Comment: The answer was a time ago, but I got some similar problem with Spring Security and Keycloak.

In my Spring Boot application I configured the adapter but couldn't use `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user')")`. If a request was send, the annotation had no effect. I fixed it now by adding `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to my security configuration.

Comment: Thanks about prePostEnabled=true !

Comment: As of today (12/18/19), the link to the adapter documentation you provided does not exist anymore (404).

Comment: This should be the latest version : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter

Answer (score 5):

here is example code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true,
                        securedEnabled = true,
                        jsr250Enabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 }
```

and

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

Apart from this code. you need to do the role mapping for realm roles and client(application roles). the application roles will be put in @PreAuthorize

Comment: what about permissions?